# SKlearn SVM RBF with unbalanced data

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, svm

I've been using Sklearn to classify some data. My data is quite unbalanced(80:20) is there a way of account for this when using the RBF kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `class_weight` argument.

Just follow this example, you can change kernel from "linear" to "RBF".
[example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html)